# PROCESS EVENTS not working inside the OUTPUT TO - PROGRESS 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am using below query to export data. But its not helping me to show the progress completion when its in inside the OUTPUT TO. Cant see the real time update( Gradually percentage increase) in view frame a(Field - cProgress). I m not sure is this possible or is there any other way to achieve this such as showing a dialog box at least if its not possible to see it in field - cProgress in view frame a.

**Note - I Cant use display statement there. Because this will be displayed in the output file which I dont want**

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cUserID AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iTotalRec AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cProgress AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE I AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iPercentage AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iComp       AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iRec        AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.


FORM
 cUser ID COLON 20
 iTotalRec COLON 20
 cProgress SKIP
 WITH FRAME a.

VIEW FRAME a.

ASSIGN
 I     = 0
 iComp = 0
 iRec  = 0
 iPercentage = 0
 .


 /* Calculating Total records*/
  FOR EACH <table> NO-LOCK:
  iRec = iRec + 1.
  END.
  /* Taking each records from the same table to update*/

  OUTPUT TO VALUE ("PATH").
  FOR EACH <table> NO-LOCK:
   I = I + 1.

   IF I = 1 THEN DO:
   /*do some more validations*/
   iComp =  iComp  + I.
   iPercentage  = 100 * (iComp / iRec).
   cProgress = STRING(iProgress) + "%". /*This percentage increase is not gradually raising in 
   view frame a..*/
   PROCESS EVENTS.

    IF iPercentage = 100 THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Record Updation Is completed".
  END.
  ELSE DO:
    I = 0
    NEXT.
  END.  
  END.
  END.
  OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is missing a DISPLAY statement. VIEW frame just visualizes the from defined in the FORM statement, but it does not display any values.

So you need a

```
DISPLAY iPercentage WITH FRAME a .
```

somewhere. What is your OS and Window system? GUI or TTY?

In TTY PROCESS EVENTS is not required, in GUI you should not use it too heavily - as it has impacts on performance.

Comment: ..Its in inside output to value statement. If I display then this frame will be there in an output file which I don't want

Answer (score 4):

Define streams to separate different outputs (as well as inputs).

Here I define one stream and set output to a file.

```
DEFINE STREAM strFile.

OUTPUT STREAM strFile TO c:/temp/file.txt.
PUT STREAM strFile "HELLO" SKIP.
DISPLAY "ALSO HELLO" FORMAT "x(20)".
OUTPUT STREAM strfile CLOSE .
```